# Problema de redirecionamento no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirecionamento

Após uma alteração nas configurações do painel administrativo do Wordpress, não foi mais possível acessar nenhuma outra página além da página inicial, o próprio painel administrativo e a aparência do menu do site ficou desconfigurada.

Quando tento acessar qualquer outra página além da inicial acontece um redirecionamento e a URL fica "duplicada".

Exemplo:

Acessando: **www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-admin**

Ocorre o redirecionamento para:

**www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-admin&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com%2Fwp-admin%2Findex.php&reauth=1**

Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Essa URL é natural do WP. É assim que ele lhe envia para o painel após a autenticação. Se você não consegue acessar o admin ou o menu ficou "desconfigurado", o problema não é esse.

Comment: Eu uso WP a um bom tempo ja, e nunca vi isso. A URL normal para acessar o wp-admin é "endereço do site/wp-admin" A pessoa que mexeu nas configurações disse que estava tentando mudar a página inicial, acredito que tenha criado um redirecionamento permanente para esta página, pois é a única que dá para acessar

Comment: A URL está ficando duplicada

Comment: nessa sua url "estranha", troque `wp-admin&redirect_to` para `wp-login&redirect_to` e veja se vc consegue logar. Ou tente logar direto por `seusite.com/wp-login.php`

Comment: Consigo logar, mas o painel não abre, sempre redireciona para a página inicial.

Comment: Você mudou o seu wp de lugar?

Comment: Não. Meu chefe que alterou alguma configuração, mas não sabe dizer exatamente onde foi. Tem alguma forma de acessar as configurações sem ser pelo painel?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31406/discussion-between-caio-felipe-pereira-and-amanda-lima).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como disse nos comentários, essa *URL* do WordPress é normal. Quando você entra em `wp-admin` sem estar logado, ele lhe envia para a página de login (`wp-login`) para que você informe as suas credências, e lhe retorna para o painel de administração. A maneira como ele faz isso é através desses parâmetros na *URL*. Acontece que, no seu caso, ela estava estranha.

Isso *pode* acontecer (i.e., *possíveis* causas, não contemplando todas elas) por alguma alteração incoerente nos *permalinks* - o que eu acho improvável - ou a mudança do local físico do WordPress. No último caso, essa mudança deve ser feita tendo em mente o fato de que você está fazendo uma **migração**, independente se pra outro servior ou pra outra pasta. O WP guarda as *URLs* do site em banco de dados, e o simples *cut and paste* da pasta não vai persistir essas informações, podendo desencadear esse tipo de problema.

Para você alterar as *URLs*, você tem [várias opções](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL). Eu, particularmente, forço a definição no `wp-config.php`, da seguinte maneira:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Lembre-se de, depois da alteração, você remover essas linhas. Caso contrário, o WP vai redefinir as *URLs* toda vez que a página for acessada, e isso é desnecessário.

Answer (score 1):

Já tive esse problema algumas vezes, e a causa pode ser variada, desde *htacess* até erro de permissões. Sempre sigo alguns passos para tentar solucionar:

**Passo I:**

Verifique se a URL do site está correta no banco de dados, você pode encontra-la na tabela *wp_options* com *option_name*: *siteurl* (geralmente é o primeiro campo).

Caso a URL esteja diferente você pode atualiza-la utilizando [esse source](http://hullen.github.io/wpsqlupdate/) do *Github* inserindo o código gerado no campo *SQL* do seu bando de dados, ou adicionar o seguinte código no arquivo *wp-config.php*:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

e/ou código abaixo no arquivo *functions.php*:

```
update_option('siteurl', 'http://example.com');
update_option('home', 'http://example.com');
```

Geralmente costumo usar o source do *github*, mas quando utilizo esse segundo meio utilizo os dois métodos para forçar a troca, você pode conferir mais detalhadamente no [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

**Passo II:**

Se for um bug do htacess, você pode resolver apenas atualizando o link permanente do site.

Tente acessar uma das "páginas" internas do seu painel administrativo, como por exemplo a de *plugins* usando esse URL:

http://seusite.com.br/wp-admin/plugins.php

Caso consiga acessar, vá até *link permanentes* ou *options-permalink* (caso o idioma seja inglês), e apenas atualize o formulário salvando as alterações. Isso ira forçar com que o seu *htacess* seja atualizado.

**Passo III:**

Caso os passos anteriores não tenham funcionado, sugiro que você mova o site para a raiz se o mesmo estiver dentro de uma sub-pasta por exemplo "novo" ou "temp" e tente "reupar" o arquivo *.htacess*.

---

Caso nenhum dos itens acima funcione, verifique a permissão dos arquivos, para pasta utiliza-se 0775 e para arquivos 0644.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tive o mesmo problema. É possível fazer a correção diretamente no banco de dados.

Na tabela `wp_options` você precisa alterar o valor da coluna
`site_url` e também `home` para o endereço do seu domínio.

A maioria das pessoas esquece de colocar o protocolo `http` ou `https` e acaba colocando somente `dominio.com.br`

Para fazer a alteração, execute a query:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'http://www.seudominio.com.br' WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Answer (score 0):

Pra caso alguém tenha feito todas as configurações e mesmo assim não resolveu, no meu caso identifiquei que o servidor estava retornando erro 404 para o arquivo index, então entrei no FTP e verifiquei que as permissões dos arquivos estavam apenas para leitura, então alterei para ler e gravar e enfim funcionou perfeitamente.

**Seguem os passos para quem não sabe como fazer:**

1. Abra o filezilla
2. Acesse o ftp da hospedagem
3. Verifique a coluna "Permissões" se um arquivo ou diretório tiver com as permissões dessa forma: -r--r--r ou algo parecido
4. Selecione os arquivos da pasta raiz (ou os arquivos que estiverem com essas permissões)
5. Clique com o botão direito do mouse e vá em "Permissões de Arquivo"
6. Selecione Ler e Executar para proprietário, grupo e público.

***Obs: Essa pode ser uma medida que vai afetar de certa forma a segurança do site, então é importante avaliar isso antes de alterar as permissões.***